# SSL certificate not found in the drop down list - IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, ssl-certificate, https

With IIS 7 I succeeded to import a new SSL certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authority store, and then to the Personal store.
In the web site binding properties in IIS manager, I wanted to bind the certificate to the required IP address and to the port 443, but could not find it in the drop down list.
I have rebooted the machine but certificate still not there.

Comment: How did you import the cert?  With a pfx file through IIS?

Comment: Run -> mmc -> Add/Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> Add -> Ok -> Computer account -> Local computer -> Finish -> Certificates (local computer) -> right click Personal\Certificates folder -> Import -> Certificate Import Wizard -> FileName: MyCertificate.cer -> Place All certificates in the following store: Personal -> Ok -> Finish -> Message: "Import was successful".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I succeeded binding the certificate to the web site:

**1/- In the IIS manager**.I clicked on the server, then double clicked "Server Certificates", then clicked on **Complete certificate Request** in the actions panel. I receipt an error message, which is a known issue (because "friendly name" property of the certificate is left blank) that I closed.

**2/- In the Certificates snap-in** (Start -> Run -> mmc -> Add/Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> Add -> Ok -> Computer account -> Local computer -> Finish -> )
- Certificates(local computer) -> right clicked Personal\Certificates folder, there I found the newly imported certificate and replaced in its properties the "friendly name" by some name.

Answer (score 5):

There are two things you need to in order for the certificate to appear in the list for IIS which you may not have done

- Make sure the certificate you are importing includes the private key
- Import the certificate into the machine account and not the user account

Comment: The imported certificate includes the private key, and into the machine account.

Comment: @Sami-L While I assume that this has been resolved a long time ago, what you wrote in another comment about the .cer file having been delivered to you from the CA means that it does in fact NOT include your private key. (Only the public key is included in the CSR, by design.) The first point in Phil's answer is very likely the problem you had.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import your pfx through IIS -->  From the IIS console, click on the server, then double click "Server Certificates", then click on "Import" in the actions panel.  You can import pfx files. You need to [convert the cert to pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate) first.

Comment: Please how to convert .cer to .pfx ?

Comment: There's a link in my answer.  It's hard to see the a link.  You'll need openssl to do the conversion.  If you're the trusting type, you can convert the cert at https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html. In the Type To Convert To box, be sure to pick PFX/PKCS#12

Comment: The certificate file is delivered by a third party authority, they also provided the text content at the end of their mail.

Comment: Sorry Sami, I don't think I can help any further.  You'll need files for the private key and certificate at a minimum.

Comment: @Edwin why would you suggest, even with a disclaimer, the possibility of sending the private key to some random site? (A HIGHLY suspicious one as it offers that service.)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I don't recommend it.  But I don't want to assume that everyone needs their website to keep a level of security that would preclude the offering of the website.  The OP didn't seem to have the skills at the time to do it himself. Maybe, to the OP, the risk of having one third party know the website's private key does not override the advantage of having a website.  I don't feel it's my place to make such a call for other people.

Comment: @Edwin To me that makes little sense, the OP is asking about setting up HTTPS for their web site on a Q&A site for professional sysadmins, that doesn't exactly fit with an argument that 'they may not care about security'. To be honest, I think that site looks like an obvious trap set up to collect keys and my humble opinion is that while you can't prevent people from walking into it said trap you can at least refrain from suggesting it.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist  I don't know.  To me, they look like a site that's trying to sell certificates.  Note, though, that I didn't say 'they may not care about security'.  I did imply that having a website with TLS, even if the key is known by an unknown third party, is much more secure than having a website with no transport security at all.

Comment: @Edwin If their real goal is actually to sell certificates, why would they undermine any credibility by also having a "service" like that? I don't buy it. Anyway, this clearly isn't leading anywhere so I think we'll just have to agree to strongly disagree.

Answer (score 0):

- Installed the .cer in my local machine
- Exported the key, while exporting it asked me options - selected extended and given a password.
- Exported file gave me .pfx file.
- Copied this .pfx file to the server and installed - that worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Phil mentioned, check if the certificate has a private key. If the certificate doesn’t have a private key, copy the Thumbprint of the certificate and run the command below.

```
certutil -repairstore my [thumbprint]
```

In my case, the issue was different though. I realized that I was using a wrong certificate while completing the certificate request in Server Certificates window. After selecting the right certificate there, it appeared in binding window.

I have added some screenshots and more details here: [Missing certificate in IIS binding](https://port135.com/2020/07/01/missing-certificate-in-iis-binding-certutil-and-private-keys/)